# Can I use side knockouts in a flush-mounted panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am installing a 36" tall electrical panel between the studs. It will be flush with the drywall. I have several questions:

Can I use the side knockouts? I could do without them, but it seems wasteful. I have no interest in mounting it over the wall.

In case NEC allows using side knockouts, is it mandatory to install cable connectors?

Comment: Mods can take down my question if they prefer separate posts.

Comment: You can also [edit] your question anytime you want. Anyone can, actually; I just updated the graphic to reflect Hillman's new packaging colors on their washers :)

Comment: And, a simple edit to make this focused on one question gets close votes retracted.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's wasteful too, and ridiculous to have to cram everything in the top.  But this is part and parcel of the decision to flush-mount inside 16" stud bays.

If you don't want to lose all the side entries, you have a few options.

- You can surface mount of course
- You can space the studs 6-8" wider in that bay, and use scraps of wood as spacers to physically hold the panel. The spacers can either be less than full stud bay depth, or have nice big holes in them.
- You can drill large holes on the centerline of the stud bay to gain access to the side knockouts.  However, you still need to use cable clamps to enter the box if you do.

Not least, if the cable were ever to be *removed*, the clearance must exist to fit a [knockout seal](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-1-2-in-Knock-Out-Seals-4-Pack-26071/100191724). So the hole must be at least 1/4" larger than the knockout.

As far as the screws, I think you are *wildly* underestimating the strength of screws. #8 deck screws are more than adequate, and are available in Torx or Robertson head for  preventing cam-out.

Drilling extra mounting holes is allowed, but not on top of a knockout.

Comment: Thanks. I think given the options you detailed, using side knockouts is out of the question for me. For the foreseeable future needs, there is plenty of space on top and bottom.

Comment: @cryptic0 feel free to drill some large holes in the studs *below* the panel and come down the adjacent stud bays and into the bottom of the panel, leaving openings up top for future expansion.  Also it helps to build a removable hatch above the panel for future access for wire pulling and installing cable clamps.

Comment: Good idea. This is a 42 space panel and I am only installing about 15 circuits, so there should be plenty entries left on both top and bottom.