# Is there any way to secure FMC or liquid tight to electrical panel post wiring?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

[image: image of conduit through knockout]So was trying to help out a buddy that is moving and noticed a couple runs 2 liquid tight and it looks like 1 using FMC to the electrical panel. The conduit doesn’t terminate properly as I found out on stack exchange already as there are no screw adapters on the runs. I saw there is a split type nut you can buy that can screw on after the fact, but the male part is not on the ends of these runs so there’s nothing to screw to.

So my question is, is there any way to secure these runs to the box without removing the conductors and conduit that is legal?

Comment: Please try to write a little more clearly.  A picture would also help.    What is "runs 2 liquid tight"?   I think you are saying you have two Liquid Tight and 1 FMC all terminating in your panel with no connectors, just loosely shoved through holes in the panel?   Is that right?

Comment: Okay. And yes. I wouldn’t call it loose, but it’s not terminated properly like I’ve seen in other panels.

Comment: Can you post photos of the improper terminations please? I'm wondering if the fitting isn't mated to the enclosure properly, or if it's a case where the fitting is simply AWOL, or if the conduit's somehow separated from the fitting?

Comment: If the conduit connectors are missing you have to disconnect the conductors but you don't have to "remove" them from the conduit.  Just disconnect from the panel, remove them from the panel which is easy because these conduits are flexible, and slip the connectors on.

Comment: For context: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/282227/when-you-have-liquidtitie-metal-clad-etc-entering-your-main-panel-is-it-comple/282228

Comment: Sorry I’ll update the post with pictures when I can. I won’t be back over there until tomorrow and then I can send some pictures. What I can say is there is definitely not fittings on the end of the liquid tight, it’s clearly just the ends are pushed through a knockout and the conduit comes about 4 more inches into the box before the conductors leave the conduit. @jay613 I think I would have to remove the conduit from the wall though, since the panel is recessed. I’d have to pull the conduit out, push a connector on the end, tighten and then push the threaded side through the knockout.

Comment: Just to add one more comment, if the fitting was at least on the end, and not secured by a nut, I could easily use something like this: https://www.zoro.com/bridgeport-fittings-split-bushing-nylon-1-trade-size-sb-383nm/i/G002494743/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=surfaces&utm_campaign=shopping%20feed&utm_content=free%20google%20shopping%20clicks&campaignid=19979164537&productid=G002494743&v=&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9rSoBhCiARIsAFOiplm5eysTGXyMkLaz-DJYBz5EnrPlipASKYSJZU_fRgY6Dw5uNzFTNFQaAgPbEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds. But the issue is there’s no termination fitting.

Comment: Also, what size are the conduits and knockouts in question?

Comment: Sorry guys, finally got back over there. I added a pic of the piece of conduit going through the knockout.

Comment: It would require only a little plaster work to open the wall and fix properly the Liquid Tight one you just added a pic of.  There is no other way to do it properly.  If you were worried about tension pulling the wires you could rig up a clamp inside the panel to prevent that, but it would not be proper and anyway that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: @jay613 well looks like the prospective buyers inspector didn’t note this as an issue, so I think he’s not going to sweat us spending time on it. Do you think the inspector was just looking for fire hazards? Anyway, I appreciate the insight and I’m going to relay everything I’m being told here. I think between the 2 of us we could do some crappy drywall patch work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's usually pretty easy to add missing connectors if flexible conduits have been inserted to boxes without the right ones.  Their flexibility is what makes it easy.  You have to disconnect the wires in the box, pull the conduit out (which is where the flexibility helps), and re-do it with the right fitting.

In your picture where the conduit has also been shoved through the wall like a barbecue skewer, you will have to open up the wall at least enough to fit the fitting (which for Liquid Tight is a lot larger than the conduit) through the wall.

If you have three of them, and they are all along the bottom of the panel, you are better off just opening a rectangle of wall there.  And if all three are transitioning from wall surface into the panel, you can leave that section of wall open stud to stud, box it beneath and behind to make a cubby, and use some 90 degree fittings and shorten the conduits to make it all look tidy and intentional.

Comment: There’s actually one entering in a similar way  from the side of the panel, And it looks like they put a hole in the stud on the side to do this. How can one fix that? Same way but now we have to make the hole in the stud larger to make the fitting.. well fit?

Comment: This should answer re side entry.https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/247611/65210